# sklearn, linear regression - How do I predict population to a future year that is outside of the test data in the input dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn

My file input is a csv containing two columns, `pop` and `year`;
`year` is an integer counting up from 0 to 67 in order. `pop` is a float showing the population for that year.

```
import sklearn.linear_model as sk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("PopulationData.csv")
regression = sk.LinearRegression()
regression.fit(df[['pop']],df['year'])
plt.scatter(df['pop'],df['year'])
plt.plot(df[['pop']],regression.predict(df[['pop']]),color="red",linewidth=3)
plt.show()
```

[image: Population Data]

This code works for showing the input data from PopulationData.csv.
However, I can't figure out how to have it predict the population from year 68 to 150 or any arbitrary number outside of the input file.

**the psuedo code that I want to accomplish is this:**

```
regression.predict([[68-150]])
#OR SOMETHING LIKE THIS
plt.plot(df[['pop']],regression.predict(df[[68-150]]),color="red",linewidth=3)
```

Comment: And what currently happens if you call `regression.predict([[150]])` ?

Comment: it returns a single negative number and nothing is on the graph. I want to predict the population from year 68 to 150 not just 150 and it seems to be giving me negative numbers for some reason.

Comment: Of course it returns a single number output, that's exactly what the sklearn doc says it should do when given a single input. If you want to predict for the entire range 68..150 then you need to pass in the range 68..150. See the doc for how to pass in a range.

Comment: @Remixt FYI your linear regression can work with data outside ranges seen in test set, but not all model types can, eg [DecisionTrees](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190503/decision-trees-and-regression-can-predicted-values-be-outside-range-of-trainin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is **using population to predict year**, when you probably want the opposite. Switching the two should solve your issue:

```
import sklearn.linear_model as sk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("PopulationData.csv")
regression = sk.LinearRegression()
regression.fit(df[['year']],df['pop'])
plt.scatter(df['year'],df['pop'])
plt.plot(df[['year']],regression.predict(df[['year']]),color="red",linewidth=3)
plt.show()

# Predict on new data
pred = regression.predict(np.arange(68, 151).reshape(-1, 1))
```

Comment: when I plot this, my graph turns into 2 straight lines.

Comment: nevermind, i forgot to swap pop and year in one line